# nonlinear dependence in autocorrelation lagged scatterplot

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, scatterplot

In lagged scatter Plot we have such a diagramm:

[image]

if we have an organized curvature in the pattern of dots, that means, nonlinear dependence between time seprated.

my question is now:

in which time series do we have nonlinear dependence? which properties should have these time series?

Comment: Some context is needed here: what kind of answer are you looking for where you ask "which time series"? Do you want a specific example?  If not, your questions appear to be extremely broad.  Please find some way to focus them and help us understand what kind of answers would best help you.

Comment: @whuber I am looking for a specific example and I would like to know the autocorrelation which type of time series generally is nonlinear

Comment: I still don't follow and I suspect many other readers would not comprehend, either. Time series are not linear or nonlinear: our *models* of them are (or are not).  It's pointless to ask for a characterization of nonlinear models: they are innumerable.